# How does the INTERVAL datatype work?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, intervals

I'm struggling to understand how INTERVAL works .

```
SELECT  INTERVAL '300' MONTH,
        INTERVAL '54-2' YEAR TO MONTH, 
        INTERVAL '11-12:10.1234567' HOUR TO SECOND
        FROM dual;
```

The output is shown as follows :

```
+25-00, +54-02, +00 11:12:10.1234567
```

What I do not get, is why does the first column show as +25 , but then the 2nd and 3rd columns are simply exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interval of 300 months is exactly the same thing as an interval of 25 years, and they are of the same data type too: year intervals, year-month intervals and month intervals are just three ways of expressing the same type.

You're shown +25-00 because one of the representations had to be picked. It could have been any of them, really.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of INTERVAL values: year-to-month and day-to-second (which includes sub-second precision). If your interval contains a year and/or month, it will be represented as years and months. Thus, 300 months is shown as 25 years, 0 months and 54 years, 2 months is shown as the same.

If you notice, your day-to-second interval is *not* displayed the same. There is a leading 00, which represents the number of days, in this case zero. If you had instead used

SELECT INTERVAL '36:12:10.1234567' HOUR TO SECOND FROM dual

You would have seen the following output:

+01 12:12:10.1234567

So, your interval value will always be displayed as either year-to-month or day-to-second, regardless if you are not actually using all of the precision. This final example should make everything clear and obvious:

SELECT INTERVAL '75:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM dual

+00 01:15:00.000000